# Neo4j constraint to prevent orphan nodes

Tags: c#, graph, neo4j, garbage-collection, directed-acyclic-graphs

A graph in Neo4j can contain an orphan node, that is a node which has no relationships associated with it.

What is a constraint that can be implemented, using Neo4j, to ensure that these types of nodes are not present at any time during graph interaction? If no such constraint exists, how can one go about achieving this requirement?

I am not sure if this counts as a garbage collection topic. If one could set the DBMS to periodically query, and eventually remove such orphan nodes, it would be considered a good solution as well - does Neo4j offer this?

I am working with C# if a solution requires implementation at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Neo4j doesn't have any constraint like this, you can find all the available constraints **[here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/)**.

You can take help of **[apoc](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)** plugin to achieve this with **`apoc.periodic.repeat`**.

**EDIT:**

> This can not be count as garbage. These types of nodes are not useful in your case but it's not always right.

You can write the query to delete such types of nodes and repeat it with the desired period.